# mongodb keeps generated files under .snapshot folder

Tags: mongodb

I am new to Mongodb. I'm running a Mongodb 3.6 services on Openshift.
I found that it keeps generated something looks like backup in the folder /var/lib/mongodb/data/.snapshot.
It's not small in size. But, I can't remove it. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it's due to the snapshot created by NetApp. We need to re-configure the snapshot policy.